# Replacing ngrx's store with Apollo's in memory cache as my single source of truth

Tags: angular, redux, graphql, ngrx, apollo

So I have been using Angular's redux implementation aka ngrx along with graphql, and recently stumbled upon Apollo and it's in-memory caching that can be used as a single source of truth, seamlessly, along with graphql queries and mutations. It also provides several features out of the box, such as optimistic UI updates, retries and several others (Find more features [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/features/optimistic-ui/)).
I am pretty far into my implementation of ngrx as a single source of truth in my application. I am wondering if anyone has implemented Apollo as their state management system and found it to be better than ngrx(or any other redux style implementations).

Comment: I think your answer can be found [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59891325/apollo-client-cache-vs-redux)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apollo Client Cache vs. Redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59891325/apollo-client-cache-vs-redux)

Comment: Yes it did, thank you so much