# Is it a good idea to replace redux with apollo and graphql when using django with react

Tags: reactjs, django, redux, graphql

I am starting a new project from scratch and I decided to use Django with React. But when I say react there are many developers who use redux as an essential library for state management but I think redux adds a lot of complexity in code. So I searched an alternative for this and I found some developers are not using redux at all instead they are using GraphQL + Apollo as an alternative. And I found this beautiful repository as well on Github that uses the Django with React but this is not using redux at all.

*Link to a package.json file of that GitHub repository* - https://github.com/mirumee/saleor-dashboard/blob/0d9f8662299a98de4c89bbdf5b8142a0e1790bc7/package.json

**So, Is this a good idea of using Apollo + GraphQL instead of redux?**

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a big difference between Redux & Apollo + GraphQL. First Apollo + GraphQL is not a state management tool, it's a way to get data from API. In my opinion, the not complex replacement for Redux as a state manager might be to use a built-in API called Context. Check this link to get started: [Context - React](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: yes, I think this answer may clarify it. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/59906102/10239185]